# htmlparse doesn't clear <style>

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, html-email

i have a problem with my html parser. I convert emails filled with html code into nice clean text, except for the "< style > content < /style >" part, which it completely ignores and i have no clue as to what i did wrong:

```
    # Remove any HTML code from our raw content
htmlparse = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', clean) \
    .replace("&nbsp;", '') \
    .replace("Ã©", 'é') \
    .replace("Ã¨", 'è') \
clean_email = htmlparse
```

what it actually should delete is:

```html
<style>      .MailHeader      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-bottom: 0px;          padding-top: 0px;          spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px;      }      .DataHeader      {          font-family: Tahoma;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #666666;          text-decoration: none;          padding-left: 15px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          vertical-align: text-top;      }      .Data      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana;          padding-left: 3px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          background: #F9F9F9;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #666666;          height: 20px !important;      }      .GridHeader      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana;          padding-left: 6px;          background: #DAEBFF;          height: 20px;      }      .DataRow      {          padding-left: 3px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #003399;      }      .GridRow      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif;          padding-left: 6px;          background: transparent;          height: 20px !important;          min-height: 1%;      }      .GridAltRow      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif;          padding-left: 6px;          background: #F9F9F9;          height: 20px !important;          min-height: 1%;      }      .li      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-left: 5px;      }      .TableHeader      {          font-family: Tahoma,calibri,verdana;          font-size: 8pt;          font-weight: bold;          height: 22px;          color: #003399;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          border-collapse: collapse;          padding-left: 5px;          padding-right: 5px;          background-color: #BBD8FF;      }      .TableSubHeader      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: middle;          padding-left: 3px;          font-weight: bold;          color: #666666;      }      .Separator      {          background-repeat: repeat-x;          background-position: center;          background: #666666;      }      .tableDetail      {          padding: 0 0 0 0;          spacing: 0 0 0 0;          border-collapse: collapse;          width: 750px;          margin-left: 5px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;      }      .style1      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-bottom: 0px;          padding-top: 0px;          spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px;          height: 18px;      }  </style>
```

What it actually does is delete style and /style but leaves the whole garbage of the stylesheet in the parsed file...

> .MailHeader      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-bottom: 0px;          padding-top: 0px;          spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px;      }      .DataHeader      {          font-family: Tahoma;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #666666;          text-decoration: none;          padding-left: 15px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          vertical-align: text-top;      }      .Data      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana;          padding-left: 3px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          background: #F9F9F9;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #666666;          height: 20px !important;      }      .GridHeader      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana;          padding-left: 6px;          background: #DAEBFF;          height: 20px;      }      .DataRow      {          padding-left: 3px;          padding-right: 15px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          font-size: 8pt;          color: #003399;      }      .GridRow      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif;          padding-left: 6px;          background: transparent;          height: 20px !important;          min-height: 1%;      }      .GridAltRow      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif;          padding-left: 6px;          background: #F9F9F9;          height: 20px !important;          min-height: 1%;      }      .li      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-left: 5px;      }      .TableHeader      {          font-family: Tahoma,calibri,verdana;          font-size: 8pt;          font-weight: bold;          height: 22px;          color: #003399;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;          border-collapse: collapse;          padding-left: 5px;          padding-right: 5px;          background-color: #BBD8FF;      }      .TableSubHeader      {          font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: middle;          padding-left: 3px;          font-weight: bold;          color: #666666;      }      .Separator      {          background-repeat: repeat-x;          background-position: center;          background: #666666;      }      .tableDetail      {          padding: 0 0 0 0;          spacing: 0 0 0 0;          border-collapse: collapse;          width: 750px;          margin-left: 5px;          border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;      }      .style1      {          font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;          vertical-align: top;          padding-bottom: 0px;          padding-top: 0px;          spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px;          height: 18px;      } Hello, this is a test mail.

Can anyone help me?

thank you guys in advance,
regards

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/502381

Comment: But more seriously, wouldn't it be easier to use a HTML parsing library?

Answer (score 1):

First remove the style itself, and then in second pass, do what you want to do.

```
import re

some = """
<style>.MailHeader { font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
vertical-align: top; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px; } 
.DataHeader { font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 8pt; color: #666666; text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px; border: solid 1px #E0E0E0; vertical-align: text-top; } 
.Data { font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana; padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 15px; border: solid 1px #E0E0E0;
\ background: #F9F9F9; font-size: 8pt; color: #666666; height: 20px !important; } 
.GridHeader { font: normal 8pt Tahoma,Verdana; padding-left: 6px; background: #DAEBFF; height: 20px; }
.DataRow { padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 15px; border: solid 1px #E0E0E0; font-size: 8pt; color: #003399; }
.GridRow { font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif; padding-left: 6px; background: transparent; 
height: 20px !important; min-height: 1%; } .GridAltRow { font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-serif;
padding-left: 6px; background: #F9F9F9; height: 20px !important; min-height: 1%; } 
.li { font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif; vertical-align: top; padding-left: 5px; }
.TableHeader { font-family: Tahoma,calibri,verdana; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; height: 22px;
color: #003399; border: solid 1px #E0E0E0; border-collapse: collapse; padding-left: 5px; 
padding-right: 5px; background-color: #BBD8FF; } 
.TableSubHeader { font: normal 8pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif;
vertical-align: middle; padding-left: 3px; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; }
.Separator { background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: center; background: #666666; }
.tableDetail { padding: 0 0 0 0; 
spacing: 0 0 0 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 750px; margin-left: 5px; border: solid 1px #E0E0E0; }
.style1 { font: normal 10pt Tahoma, Verdana, Sans-Serif; vertical-align: top; padding-bottom:
0px; padding-top: 0px; spacing: 0px 0px 0px 0px; height: 18px; }
</style>
<h1>Hello, this is a test mail.</h1>
"""

some1 = re.sub(r'<style>.*</style>', '', some, flags=re.DOTALL)

print some1
```

Result :

```
I have no name!@sla-334:~/stack_o$ python stack_o_html.py 


<h1>Hello, this is a test mail.</h1>
```

Now, do what you want to do with this html.

Answer (score 1):

I kinda fixed it myself by reparsing trough the parsed text and using this as parameters

```
cleaner = re.sub(r'{.*}', '', clean_email)\
      .replace(".MailHeader", '') \
```

Ill try out your solutions